# Problems importing custom node-modules library

Tags: node-modules, commonjs, esmodules

I'm developing a library for a Typescript codebase that I want to install via `npm`, but I am not able to import exported members as I would expect. My primary code is Typescript running on v4.7.4. My approach to exposing the imports from my library is as follows:

I have an index.ts that has a `export * from "path/to/Component";` for each file that contains members that I want to expose.

This compiles to:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__exportStar(require("path/to/Component"), exports);
```

When I import the component in my application via `import { Component } from "library";`, I get an error `Error: Cannot find module 'library/Component'`, even though I can see that `/node_modules/library/build/index.js` is in the require stack.